# How to Get UserToken in APIController class and associate it with other service principal for calling other APIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

I have created an Azure API App and associated this with Azure service principal . In the controller (derived from `APIController` Class), I put the authorize attribute on class level and user is getting a login page while accessing the api. Now I want to access some azure resource from Azure API. I am using below code for getting the token

```
string tenant = "***********";
string aadInstance = "*********";

string authority = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, aadInstance, tenant);

var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
var clientCredential = new ClientCredential("*********", "*****");

var authResult = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://database.windows.net/", clientCredential);
return authResult.Result.AccessToken;
```

I am getting the token , but I think this token is not generated in the context of the logged in user. There is one overload of `AcquireTokenAsync` method which is taking `UserAssertion` Parameter but I am not sure , how can I set it from the values that I am getting in `APIController` class.

Thanks,

Abhishek